# Haskell: Parsing escape characters in single quotes

Tags: parsing, haskell, character-encoding

I'm currently making a scanner for a basic compiler I'm writing in Haskell. One of the requirements is that any character enclosed in single quotes (') is translated into a character literal token (type T_Char), and this includes escape sequences such as '\n' and '\t'. I've defined this part of the scanner function which works okay for most cases:

```
scanner ('\'':cs)       |   (length cs) == 0            =   error "Illegal character!"
                         |  head cs == '\\'             =   mkEscape (head (drop 1 cs)) : scanner (drop 3 cs)
                         |  head (drop 1 cs) == '\''    =   T_Char (head cs) : scanner (drop 2 cs)


                         where
                            mkEscape        :: Char -> Token
                            mkEscape 'n'    = T_Char '\n'
                            mkEscape 'r'    = T_Char '\r'
                            mkEscape 't'    = T_Char '\t'
                            mkEscape '\\'   = T_Char '\\'
                            mkEscape '\''   = T_Char '\''
```

However, this comes up when I run it in GHCi:

```
Main> scanner "abc '\\' def"
[T_Id "abc", T_Char '\'', T_Id "def"]
```

It can recognise everything else but gets escaped backslashes confused with escaped single quotes. Is this something to do with character encodings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with the parser regarding your problem. To Haskell, the string will be read as

```
abc '\' def
```

because Haskell also has string escapes. So when it reaches the first quotation mark, `cs` contains the char sequence `\' def`. Obviously `head cs` is a backslash, so it will run `mkEscape`.

The argument given is `head (drop 1 cs)`, which is `'`, thus `mkEscape` will return `T_Char  '\''`, which is what you saw.

---

Perhaps you should call

```
scanner "abc '\\\\' def"
```

The 1st level of `\` is for the Haskell interpreter, and the 2nd level is for `scanner`.

Comment: I see. Does this mean it will work okay when reading a file in rather than using the interpreter?